# Wait on an ordinary function which calls an async function

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

For a project, I want to be able to have simultaneously a sync and async version of a library, the sync version has most logic parts and the async must call the sync version in a async way. For example I have a class which gets an http requester in constructor, this requester handle sync or async internally:

```
    .
├── async
│   └── foo.py
├── foo.py
└── main.py
└── requester.py

# requester.py
class Requester():
    def connect():
        return self._connect('some_address')

class AsynRequester():
    async def connect():
        return await self._connect('some_address')

# foo.py                                                                                                                                              
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, requester):
        self._requester = requester

    def connect(self):
        self.connect_info = self._requester.connect('host') # in async version it would be called by an await internally

# async/foo.py                                                                                                                                        
from foo import Foo as RawFoo

class Foo(RawFoo):
    async def connect(self):
        return await super(RawFoo, self).connect()

# main.py                                                                                                                                             
from async.foo import Foo # from foo import Foo                                                                                                       
from requester import AsynRequester # from requester import Requester

def main():
    f = Foo(AsyncRequester()) # or Foo(Requester()) where we use sync requester

    await f.connect() # or f.connect() if we are using sync methods
```

But async `connect` finally calls the sync connect of sync class type of `Foo` (which is parent of async class) which internally calls `requester.connect` function. It is impossible because `requester.connect` internally has called `await connect` when it had being used in async mode but it is calling without any await.

All of my tests have been written for sync version, because async tests is not efficient as they must be, also I must write tests for one version and be sure that both versions would work correctly. How can I have both version at the same time which are using the same logic and just the I/O calls are separated.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious if the approach outlined in my answer addresses your question?

Comment: Sorry I am curious too, but because of some pressures in my work, I could not check it completely yet and just read the function color link which has addressed my question but no solution was given. I prefer to have a simple logic part and able to use it asynchronously and even multi process or multi threaded, it makes sense that the structure which a logic run on it could be separated from the logic itself, but it seems challenging.

Comment: No problem. The function color link describes in general the issue with two kinds of functions, and it is the reason why your logic must be written in async-style. However, other than using `await` everywhere, I think you can make it basically sequential, and have the same code work for the sync and the async case. My answer describes how to achieve that, with sufficient effort.

Answer (score 3):

> the sync version has most logic parts and the async must call the sync version in a async way

It is possible, but it's a lot of work, as you're effectively fighting the [function color](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) mismatch. Your logic will have to be written in an async fashion, with some hacks to allow it to work in sync mode.

For example, a logic method would look like this:

```
# common code that doesn't assume it's either sync or async
class FooRaw:
    async def connect(self):
        self.connect_info = await self._to_async(self._requester.connect(ENDPOINT))

    async def hello_logic(self):
        await self._to_async(self.connect())
        self.sock.write('hello %s %s\n' % (USERNAME, PASSWORD))
        resp = await self._to_async(self.sock.readline())
        assert resp.startswith('OK')
        return resp
```

When running under asyncio, methods like `connect` and `readline` are coroutines, so their return value must be awaited. On the other hand, in blocking code `self.connect` and `sock.readline` are sync functions that return concrete values. But `await` is a syntactic construct which is either present or missing, you cannot switch it off at run-time without duplicating code.

To allow the same code to work in sync and async modes, `FooRaw.hello_logic` **always** awaits, leaving it to the `_to_async` method to wrap the result in an awaitable when running outside asyncio. In async classes `_asincify` awaits its argument and return the result, it's basically a no-op. In sync classes it returns the received object without awaiting it - but is still defined as `async def`, so it can be awaited. In that case `FooRaw.hello_logic` is still a coroutine, but one that never suspends (because the "coroutines" it awaits are all instances of `_to_async` which doesn't suspend outside asyncio.)

With that in place, the async implementation of `hello_logic` doesn't need to do anything except choose the right `requester` and provide the correct `_to_async`; its `connect` and `hello_logic` inherited from `FooRaw` do the right thing automatically:

```
class FooAsync(FooRaw):
    def __init__(self):
        self._requester = AsyncRequester()

    @staticmethod
    async def _to_async(x):
        # we're running async, await X and return the result
        result = await x
        return result
```

The sync version will, in addition to implementing `_to_async`, need to wrap the logic methods to "run" the coroutine:

```
class FooSync(FooRaw):
    def __init__(self):
        self._requester = SyncRequester()

    @staticmethod
    async def _to_async(x):
        # we're running sync, X is the result we want
        return x

    # the following can be easily automated by a decorator

    def connect(self):
        return _run_sync(super().connect())

    def hello_logic(self):
        return _run_sync(super().hello_logic())
```

Note that it is possible to run the coroutine outside the event loop only because the `FooSync.hello_logic` is a coroutine in name only; the underlying requester uses blocking calls, so `FooRaw.connect` and others never really suspend, they complete their execution in a single run. (This is similar to a generator that does some work without ever yielding anything.) This property makes the `_run_sync` helper straightforward:

```
def _run_sync(coro):
    try:
        # start running the coroutine
        coro.send(None)
    except StopIteration as e:
        # the coroutine has finished; return the result
        # stored in the `StopIteration` exception
        return e.value
    else:
        raise AssertionError("coroutine suspended")
```